# 'User' object has no attribute '_committed'

Tags: django, django-models

Im making a simple app that authenticates users and lets them upload files. Im having a problem where when i try to add a model with user as a foreign key to my database I get this error:

```
'User' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

**models.py**

```
fs = FileSystemStorage(location='/media/uploads')

class FileInstance(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=fs)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = FileInstance(request.FILES['file'], request.user)
        file.save()
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

**upload.html**

```
{% extends 'commons/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Dodaj plik {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Internal Server Error: /storage/upload/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/jch/PycharmProjects/2019Z_PAMIW_git_gr4/pamw2/storage/views.py", line 36, in upload_file
    file.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 741, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 779, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 848, in _save_table
    for f in non_pks]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 848, in <listcomp>
    for f in non_pks]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 286, in pre_save
    if file and not file._committed:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 257, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I work around it ? Is my data model even correct and if not how do I change it?

**After modifications**

**models.py**

```
class FileInstanceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FileInstance
        fields = ['file']
```

**views.py**

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileInstanceForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('files.html')
    else:
        form = FileInstanceForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {form: form})
```

**upload.html**

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
```

My form is not showing propertly. I have no way to attach the file and the html doesn't render. Its just this:

[image]

Comment: You can't instantiate a model using positional arguments, you need to use keyword args. But actually here you shouldn't be doing that either, you should be using the form, checking out is valid, then calling its save method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did what you said. By the book. But the filepicker doesn't render and therefore form is always invalid